# Issues with VS Code, Azure Cosmos DB and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code

Playing with Mongodb and VSCode, im connected via a scrapbook to a docker instance of mongodb (4.04) but any basic queries are failing,

Ie if i run

```
USE Admin
```

I get the error:

```
at 1:1: Error near line 0, column 0: mismatched input 'use' expected <EOF>' Please check syntax
```

and when i try to create a user following mongodb documentation from: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

I get the use error above, if i remove that i get an error saying:

```
db.createUser at 2:1 Error near line 5, column 45: 'mismatched input 'db' expecting '}". Please check syntax
```

but i can get things like below to work successfully!

```
db.getCollection.find()
```

EDIT ******

Just installed mongodb community edition of 4.0 (without the server) so i can use the mongo shell.  Everything works in the shell but fails in VS!? pics below

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're typing in capital letters, because if I try:

```
USE Admin
```

> 2018-11-30T12:43:57.089+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:4

But:

```
use Admin
```

> switched to db Admin

I'm pretty sure it's the same kind of error for the second one.

A lot of systems are case-sensitive, which is a reasonable default because A and a are not the same character (in term of character encoding, not in term of a human reading it).

Comment: thanks for a reply Geoffroy, sadly no matter what case sensitivfy i use, i get the same error.  I have now installed mongodb community edition (without the server) to see if things work straight in the mongodb shell.

Comment: @Staggerlee011 if id doesn't work in VS perhaps it's better not to use a crappy VS integration and stick to the shell, no?

Comment: yeah thats what im having to do! just interested to resolve it, as i do use VS code a lot, so would handy to keep a single tool for things.

Comment: @Staggerlee011 that's a pure personal point of view, but that's not always the best solution to have a jack-of-all-trade tool: you're not gonna need to access your database very often if you're writing code, it's the code, while being executed, which will access the database for you